# How to format text that is inserted at end of spreadsheet with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to insert a formatted signature and a number in separate rows at end of a spreadsheet. I have found that I can easily append the values I want however I cannot format the signature variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function signNote(){
//gets and signs for current user
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email)
if(self){
 // gets full name
var name = self.getFullName();
//gets Clinician Profile Information
var clinicianProfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('idGoeshere')
var clinicianInfoFile = clinicianProfile.getSheetByName(name)
var license = clinicianInfoFile.getRange('D5').getValue()
var signature = clinicianInfoFile.getRange('D6').getValue()

//Fills in signature and license
var noteSign = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var insertSignatureLign = noteSign.insertRowAfter(noteSign.getLastRow())
var insertSignature = insertSignatureLign.getDataRange()


noteSign.appendRow(['Signature' , signature])
noteSign.appendRow(['License Number' , license])
```

Comment: please ignore the insertSignatureLign and insertSignature variables. I forgot to clear them before sharing

Comment: Try using copyTo() instead of appendRow() appendRow just copies the data not the formatting.[reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))

Comment: Hello @BladeRohloff, did Cooper's suggestion work for your situation?